# If the unit tangent vector T has constant length, under what additional conditions does the derivative of T with respect to time have constant length?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, curvature

I am taking Calculus 3 and I am learning about the unit tangent vector T.
I know that dT/dt does not always have constant length. My question is under what additional conditions does dT/dt have constant length. I have an idea of 4 additional conditions, of which I'll kind of prove below.

Let's assume a 2D example for simplicity.
r = x i + y j
dr/dt = dx/dt i + dy/dt j
||dr/dt|| = sqrt( (dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2) = Let's call this speed
T = dr/dt / speed = (dx/dt / speed) i + (dy/dt / speed) j
Also I will be using x' for dx/dt and x'' for d2x/dt2
dT/dt = (x''*(speed^2) - x'*(x'*x'' + y'*y''))/(speed^3) i + (y''*(speed^2) - y'*(x'*x'' + y'*y''))/(speed^3) j
So our first condition will be that speed or ||dr/dt|| is constant.

Let's factor speed out of dT/dt and only focus on the numerators of the x and y components.
(x''*(speed^2))^2 + (y''*(speed^2))^2 should be constant if 2 conditions apply:

One speed is constant. We already assumed this with our first condition

Two also (x'')^2 + (y'')^2 is constant.

(x'*(x'*x'' + y'*y''))^2 + (y'*(x'*x'' + y'*y''))^2 should be constant if 2 conditions apply:

One (x')^2 + (y')^2 is constant. We already assumed this when we assumed speed is constant

Two x'*x'' + y'*y'' is constant. This is a new condition.

All together, we get the following conclusion:
If we have unit tangent vector T, then dT/dt has constant length if and only if

One speed or (x')^2 + (y')^2 is constant

Two (x'')^2 + (y'')^2 is constant

Three x'*x'' + y'*y'' is constant

Can someone please tell me if this is right? And also provide an intuitive explanation for why these 3 conditions must hold?
Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

I will use a bit of mechanics here... Acceleration of point is a sum of two components:

$$\vec{a}=\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=\vec{a_t}+\vec{a_n}$$

$$\vec{a_t}=\frac{dv}{dt}\vec{u_t}$$

$$\vec{a_n}=\frac{v^2}{R_k}\vec{u_n}$$

$\vec{u_t},\vec{u_n}$ are unit vectors, first is tangent to trajectory, the second is perpendicular to it. $R_k$ is the radius of the trajectory at the given point.

**In your problem $\vec{T}$ is actually velocity $\vec{v}$ of a point along some trajectory in space.**

Because $\vec{v}$ has constant length, $dv/dt=0$ which means that $\vec{a_t}=0$. This leaves only the second component so the intensitiy of it is:

$$a=a_n=\frac{v^2}{R_k}$$

You know that $v$ is constant and you want $a$ to be constant. The only possibility is to have constant $R_k$ as well. And the only curve that has constant $R_k$ is a circle or a part of it!

Comment: There's no reason $\vec T$ has to be the actual velocity vector. It's just the unit vector in that direction. Of course, if you have constant speed motion, then $\vec T$ is a constant multiple of $\vec v$.

Answer (score 0):

Curvature $\kappa$ is defined as the magnitude of $\dfrac{d\vec T}{ds}$, where $s$ is the arclength of the curve. The chain rule gives us
$$\frac{d\vec T}{dt} = \frac{d\vec T}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} = \kappa\vec N\,\upsilon,$$
where $\upsilon = \dfrac{ds}{dt}$ is the speed and $\vec N$ is called the principal normal.

Your condition that $d\vec T/dt$ have constant magnitude is therefore the condition that $\kappa\upsilon$ be constant. If your speed is constant, this is equivalent to constant $\kappa$. In the plane this is a circle, but in space there are zillions of examples (among them circular helices, but lots more complicated). And if you imagine a particle changing speed inversely proportional to the curvature, then you get zillions more examples.

(At this point you might want to look a little bit at an undergraduate differential geometry text. Immediately accessible is [mine](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf), if you're interested. See the beginning of the second section.)

Comment: By the way the only reason I wanted to know this was because I know N = (dT/dt) / ||dT/dt|| but I want to know when I can calculate N with (dv/dt) / ||dv/dt||. It turns out you can only calculate N with (dv/dt) / ||dv/dt|| when ||dv/dt|| stays constant. Anyways my question is why in 2D is the only curve that has ||dT/dt|| be constant a circle?

Comment: Zachary, that’s false. You only get a circle if speed is constant. If not, take any curve with nowhere-zero curvature $\kappa$ and move with speed $3/\kappa$. So you get all curves with nowhere-zero curvature.

Comment: Yea, you're right I forgot that k*v has to be constant not k. I'm sure there are plenty of curves in 2D besides circles that hold k*v constant.

Comment: As I just said, *any* curve will work, appropriately parametrized, provided it has no points of zero curvature.

Comment: @ZacharyKatz: If you're satisfied with the answer, please accept it, so that the question does not permanently stay on the unanswered list! If you're not, let's see another follow-up question. :)